# Cannot activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Unale to activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure in Site Collection Features. I was told I need to activate this in order to have Design Manager enabled. 
It shows the following error message

> Sorry, something went wrong An unexpected error has occurred.
>   TECHNICAL DETAILS
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. Correlation
>   ID: be85879e-1095-6000-33d3-0635dc15345c
>
> Date and Time: 23/08/2018 02:48:05

Comment: Have you checked the log with *be85879e-1095-6000-33d3-0635dc15345c*

Answer (score 0):

Have you access to the server ?

You can do it using Powershell. This link can Help :

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity "PublishingSite" -url "http://intranet.contessa.com"
```

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/03/activate-publishing-feature-using-powershell-in-sharepoint.html